# How to achieve Form's TransparencyKey behavior in panel?

Tags: c#, transparency

I'm programming in c#.
The **System.Windows.Forms.Form** has **TransparencyKey** property.

Is there any way to achieve this property's behavior in **System.Windows.Forms.Panel**?

Comment: See the related links on the right margin.

Comment: Sure. Actually Color.Transparent is the default for Panel.BackColor. Or you set yourPanel.Backcolor = this.BackColor. A full see-through depends on the form also being see-through though! You can't see though a Panel onto the desktop if the form is opaque!

Comment: It is a feature that can only work on toplevel windows.  Forms.  An operating system restriction.  They did actually also make it work on child windows, starting at Windows 8.  Possible because Aero can no longer be turned off on that version.  But that's future music in .NET, Windows 7 is the new XP.  Panel otherwise supports transparency well, it has the ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor style turned on.  Just set the BackColor property to Color.Transparent and you'll see the Parent in the background.